# Регулярное выражение. Исключить перенос

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть переменная s

```
13:50 - 15:20
4. ОСНОВЫ БУХГАЛТЕРСКОГО УЧЕТА
Рулева А.Е.
15:30 - 17:00
5. ИНОСТРАННЫЙ ЯЗЫК В ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНОЙ ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ
Цой А.И./ Гузенко Л.В.
17:10 - 18:40,   18:50 - 20:20
6,7. СИСТЕМНОЕ ПРОГРАММИРОВАНИЕ
```

Мне нужно время записать в список вот так:

```
TIME: ['13:50 - 15:20', '15:30 - 17:00', '17:10 - 18:40,   18:50 - 20:20']
```

Я написал вот такой шаблон выражения:

```
patterTIME = r'[0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9]\s*\-*\—*\s*[0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9]\,*\s*\s*[0-9]*[0-9]*\:*[0-9]*[0-9]*\s*\-*\—*\s*[0-9]*[0-9]*\:*[0-9]*[0-9]*'
```

Но, к сожалению, берется перенос и цифра после него. Я получил такой результат:

```
TIME: ['13:50 - 15:20\n4', '15:30 - 17:00\n5', '17:10 - 18:40,   18:50 - 20:20']
```

Как исключить перенос(\n) в patter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбирай:

- Замени `\s` на `[ \t]`.
- Замени `\s` на `(?!\r?\n)\s` в тех местах, где надо запретить перенос.

  И про группу (вероятно, незахватываемую) не забудь, а то там дальше звёздочка.
- Используй `^` и `$` если питон поддерживает многострочный режим.

Comment: Спасибо! Я так долго искал решение проблемы!